# Using cypress-plugin-snapshots returns .toMatchSnapshot is not a function

Tags: plugins, snapshot, cypress

I'm trying to use cypress-plugin-snapshots to take some snapshots of JavaScript objects.

I have followed the *Configure Cypress.io* instructions on https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-plugin-snapshots but when I run my test (below) I receive the following error

`1) Check snapshots Should match snapshot:
     TypeError: expectedData.toMatchSnapshot is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (https://www.bbc.com/__cypress/tests?p=cypress/integration/data_driven.js-917:24:18)`

My test file is:

```
describe('Check snapshots', function () {
    it('Should match snapshot', () => {
    const expectedData = {
      fonts: 
       [ { familyName: 'Helvetica', isCustomFont: false, glyphCount: 10 },
         { familyName: 'Gurmukhi MN', isCustomFont: false, glyphCount: 33 } ]
    }

      expectedData.toMatchSnapshot();
    });
  });
```

I'm relatively new to both JS (and Cypress) so I am not sure exactly what it is I am doing wrong. If anyone has experience sorting this issue out I'd be really grateful for some input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to wrap your object with `expect`:

```js
expect(expectedData).toMatchSnapshot()
```

Comment: Thank you so much bkucera, I really appreciate it.